# How to determine if element can have html children?

Tags: javascript

Only Internet Explorer seems to have the element property: `canHaveHtml` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533547%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [Dottoro](http://help.dottoro.com/ljwqncls.php)). I can't seem to find anything in other browsers to emulate it, other than using a regex with a list of tagnames. Is there a way to determine this in Chrome, Firefox etc?

For example is there a way of checking for the `innerHTML` property and is this 100% equivalent?

Comment: For what purpose do you need to check the canHaveHtml property? Manybe it can be done using a different property

Comment: Isn't it possible to add children to all tags? since its valid in html/xml? Do you have any error returned when doing so?

Comment: @GrzegorzKaczan — `<input> foo </input>` is not valid in HTML.

Comment: Can't test at the moment, but can you create a test using `document.createElement(elementToTest).appendChild('span');` (though now I'm not sure that `appendChild()` can even be chained like that...)

Comment: .appendChild expects Node, not a string.

Comment: @Quentin indeed its not valid. i meant as in xml tag that can be extended through DOM and no error is returned for that case.

Comment: Just tested in Chrome, you *can* append a child to an `<input>` elements (using the HTML5 doctype), but it's not displayed anyway. So the property just doesn't have any sense in Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can't seem to find anything in other browsers to emulate it, other
>   than using a regex with a list of tagnames.

It may not seem elegant or clever, but creating a whitelist (or blacklist) is the easiest, fastest, and most reliable approach. You don't need a regular expression; you can create use a simple structure such as an associative array.

```
// blacklist approach

var noChildren = {
    input: true,
    meta: true,
    br: true,
    link: true,
    img: true

    // other properties here
};

function canHaveChildren(tagName) {
    tagName = tagName.toLowerCase();
    alert(noChildren[tagName] === undefined);
}

canHaveChildren("BR");
canHaveChildren("div");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FTbWa/
Reusable function: [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/Daniel-Hug/7349e15d04384c841a421b4f071f9603)

This paradigm is not without precedence; it's used in many script libraries and HTML parsers/sanitizers. For example, look at the source of jQuery and you'll notice many element-specific tests and arrays of element names and attribute names.

Comment: Is there a definitive list somewhere on which elements can and can't have kids?

Comment: Yes, that's all defined clearly within the spec. This is a good quick list: http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/elements.html and so is this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/HTML5/HTML5_element_list. Click on an element name to see what it can/can't contain.

Comment: Where's the difference between object literal and regex whitelist? The regex imho is more expressive, and [mostly even faster](http://www.google.de/search?q=jsperf+regex+vs+lookup)

Comment: I was hoping there was a simpler answer than a hardcoded white/black list but which is faster, regex or an object?  Anyway, in the absence of a better answer, I will accept this one tomorrow.  It's not what I was hoping to find but it does kinda answer the question in as much as there isn't a better solution.

Comment: @Bergi - nothing wrong w/ a simple regex here. The object literal approach is more flexible if you want to build out more detail around each tag in the future, e.g. `input: { children: false, foo: "bar" }`.

Comment: You missed `<hr>`. Maybe there are more such elements.

Answer (score 5):

I believe there is no specifications about that:

http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#concept-node-append

For instance, in Firefox, Chrome and Safari, you *can* actually add nodes to elements like `<input>` for example:

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
var div = document.createElement("div");

div.textContent = 'hello';

console.log(input.outerHTML, input.childNodes.length);

input.appendChild(div);

console.log(input.outerHTML, input.childNodes.length);
```

They're just not rendered. But they're considered children of the `input` node in both case. In case of Firefox the `outerHTML` is not changed, only the `childNodes` length reports 1, in case of Chrome and Safari the `outerHTML` changes from `<input>` to `<input></input>`.
In Firefox, as opposite of Safari and Chrome, `innerHTML` returns actually the children's HTML, even if it's not rendered and is not returned in `outerHTML`.

**Update**:
As @Bergi pointed out in @MårtenWikström answer, approaches like the previous I made doesn't really works well on element that can have content, like `textarea`, or even `title`, but not HTML content. Therefore, a better `canHaveHTML` could be something like that:

```
// Improving the `canHaveHTML` using `canHaveChildren`,
// using the approach shown by Mårten Wikström
function canHaveChildren(node) {
  // Uses the native implementation, if any.
  // I can't test on IE, so maybe it could be worthy to never use
  // the native implementation to have a consistent and controlled
  // behaviors across browsers. In case, just remove those two lines
  if (node && node.canHaveChildren)
    return node.canHaveChildren();

  // Returns false if it's not an element type node; or if it has a end tag.
  // Use the `ownerDocument` of the `node` given in order to create
  // the node in the same document NS / type, rather than the current one,
  // useful if we works across different windows / documents.
  return node.nodeType === 1 && node.ownerDocument
      .createElement(node.tagName).outerHTML.indexOf("></") > 0;
}

function canHaveHTML(node) {
  // See comment in `canHaveChildren` about native impl.
  if (node && node.canHaveHTML)
    return node.canHaveHTML();

  // We don't bother to create a new node in memory if it
  // can't have children at all
  if (!canHaveChildren(node))
    return false;

  // Can have children, then we'll check if it can have
  // HTML children.
  node = node.ownerDocument.createElement(node.tagName);

  node.innerHTML = "<b></b>";

  // if `node` can have HTML children, then the `nodeType`
  // of the node just inserted with `innerHTML` has to be `1`
  // (otherwise will be likely `3`, a textnode).
  return node.firstChild.nodeType === 1;  
}
```

Tested in Firefox, Chrome and Safari; that should cover all the nodes and all the scenarios.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following function to determine whether a named element may have children.

However, as noted by ZER0, this is probably more like a replacement for IE's [canHaveChildren](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) rather than [canHaveHtml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533547%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), as it returns true for any tag name that is "supposed" to not be empty.

```
function canHaveHtml(tag) { 
    return document.createElement(tag).outerHTML.indexOf("></") > 0; 
}
```

It uses the fact that a newly created element, that cannot (or should not) have content, has `outerHtml` without an end tag.

For example:

```
document.createElement("input").outerHTML === "<input>"
```

and

```
document.createElement("div").outerHTML === "<div></div>"
```

Comment: No, it actually only tests whether the element may have content (should not be empty). Textareas may have content. So it may or may not be helpful depending on the use case.

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought the OP asked for HTML *element* contents (aka *children*), not for *text* content (as in textareas, titles, scripts, styles). Not sure what IEs `canHaveHtml` does…

Comment: IE has [canHaveChildren](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for this purpose, so it makes a difference between "HTML" children and children (like text nodes). I believe that this implementation is more `canHaveChildren` rather than `canHaveHTML`.

Comment: @ZER0 You are right. I've updated my answer to make this clear. However, I've decided to not delete it as I still think it may be helpful.

Comment: It's definitely helpful. Actually, my answer suffer of the same problem because you can actually add HTML nodes to `textarea`, and they appear on `innerHTML` too. I'm going to update my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am assuming that if the element does not have a innerHTML property, it should have a value or a src or a type property. Cant think of any other way. You could add specific TagName checks to handle specific cases which the code below fails to handle.

```
function CheckInnerHTMLSupport(oElement)
{
    var oDiv = document.createElement(oElement.tagName);
    if('canHaveHTML' in oDiv)
    {
        return oDiv.canHaveHTML;
    }
    var bSupportsInnerHTML = oDiv.type === undefined && oDiv.value === undefined && oDiv.src === undefined;
    return bSupportsInnerHTML;
}
```

Comment: This is not robust: canvas, img, link, meta are not captured, to name a few. You'd better look up the specification and create a method which covers all known cases.

Comment: I believe that `canvas` can actually contains children.